# How is the cable flashzebra.com #0138 better than #0126 for a Canon flash; Why this cable has the same contacts as a Canon hotshoe?

Tags: remote, pocket-wizard

I asked this questions on an email I sent to support at Flashzebra.com
This is the answer I received:

"1) There is a listing of product attributes for the FZ #0126 and the FZ

## 0138 in ad copy for each (link below).  Note that these are not identical.

2) Neither the FZ #0126 or the FZ #0138 supports TTL, but not that devices
you connect then to also do not support TTL, so this is not an issue.

3) In general, the FZ #0138 is specifically engineered for the Canon
version of the ISO hotshoe .The FZ #0126 is general purpose hotshoe usable on most flash units with an ISO type hotshoe."

I still would like to know why the 0138 has the same pins as the camera hotshoe?
What is the purpose of those pins if the cable does not support TTL? 
If this cable is enginnered specifically for Canon flash units, how is that?
What makes this cable different than any other mini-phone-to-hotshoe adaptor?

Answer (score 1):

The standard, single-contact ISO hotshoe cable will work just fine with *most* Canon cameras in fully-manual, trigger-only mode. It will not work with the original Digital Rebel/KISS/300D, the 10D or the 35mm film EOS Elan, since they use one of the auxiliary pins to trigger the flash in all modes (the centre contact on the shoe doesn't do anything related to firing the flash). It's the same reason why most trigger-only wireless flash triggers won't work with those cameras.

If you are not using one of these oddly-configured Canons, the simpler cable will work as expected.